# which linux configuration is used my my system?

Tags: command-line

is there any command in linux ,which gives every specification of currently running linux distro,, 
including shell, desktop enviroment(like GNOME or KDE) ,display manager (gdm or ligthdm or kdm )and every other minute details that system is having,

similar to when we go to buy a laptop we are a given with a complete specification list,,anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the System Monitor is the closest I can think of to see what your system is running.
For example, Gnome, KDE, ect.. all show up in the apps list. If you want details about your hardware, click the menu button (Gear, top right), then "about this computer".